# Paid app after phone reset missing

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset, paid-apps

I have bought an app 3 months back. 
Recently I reset my phone to factory settings. 
I could not be able to find my app on google store. ( the one I bought 3 months back) 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, are you not able to find the app in the Play Store at all, or does it show that you don't own it? What's the name of the app? The app could have been delisted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the 'My Apps' page and tap 'All'. The app should be listed here and you should be able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are signed in with the right Google Account on the Google Play Store.

You can find all your previously installed/paid apps at `My Apps -> All`.

Hope my answer helps. For any questions just leave a comment below.